# how to remove specific word from an array that is starts with "[ "?

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a array that contains many sentences. I have split this sentences into words and make another array. I want that the words that id start with "[" and end with "]" are removed from my array.

ex.

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
print(sentences[0])
z= np.array(sentences)
```

sentence: [42] On 20 January 1987, he also turned out as substitute for Imran Khan's side in an exhibition game at Brabourne Stadium in Bombay, to mark the golden jubilee of Cricket Club of India.

```
words = z[0].split()
words= list(words)
print(words)
```

after split into words : ['[42]', 'On', '20', 'January', '1987,', 'he', 'also', 'turned', 'out', 'as', 'substitute', 'for', 'Imran', "Khan's", 'side', 'in', 'an', 'exhibition', 'game', 'at', 'Brabourne', 'Stadium', 'in', 'Bombay,', 'to', 'mark', 'the', 'golden', 'jubilee', 'of', 'Cricket', 'Club', 'of', 'India.']

Now I want to remove **[42]** from my array. and then join this words into sentence. How can I do that?
I tried this way. but this is not working. it remove whole array and print **None**.

```
for i in words:
  if i[0]=="[":
    b=words.remove(i)
    print(b)
  else:
    print("")
```

Comment: Did you mean: `words = words[1:]`?

Comment: yes. remove [42] and then print "On 20 January 1987, he also turned out as substitute for Imran Khan's side in an exhibition game at Brabourne Stadium in Bombay, to mark the golden jubilee of Cricket Club of India."

Comment: list.remove does not return any value, so your `b=...` assignment does not make sense.

Comment: is it works for array ? then I convert list to array.

Comment: After you have removed the '42', you can convert to a string with: `sentence = ' '.join(words)`

Comment: No, simply do `words.remove(i)` without printing or assigning anything. After the for loop your `words` will have the matching elements removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using list comprehension as below:

```
sentence = "[42] On 20 January 1987, he also turned out as substitute for Imran Khan's side in an exhibition game at Brabourne Stadium in Bombay, to mark the golden jubilee of Cricket Club of India."
words = sentence.split()
words = [ w for w in words if w[0]!='[' and w[-1]!= ']' ]
filtered = ' '.join(words)
print(filtered)
"On 20 January 1987, he also turned out as substitute for Imran Khan's side in an exhibition game at Brabourne Stadium in Bombay, to mark the golden jubilee of Cricket Club of India."
```

Comment: Add this line print(" ".join(words)). It will join the list with whitespaces and you will get your sentence back.

Comment: Could also use the builtins `w.startswith('[')` and `w.endswith(']')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex (you won't need to split the sentence):

```
import re
sentence = "[42] On 20 January 1987, he also turned out as substitute for Imran Khan's side in an exhibition game at Brabourne Stadium in Bombay, to mark the golden jubilee of Cricket Club of India."
re.sub(r'\[.+\]','',sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you implement a matching function to match the words you want filtered out:

```py
def check_word(word: str) -> bool:
    """Returns True iff the word starts with [ and ends with ]."""

    return word.startswith('[') and word.endswith(']')
```

You can then use it in conjunction with `itertools.filterfalse()` which will leave you with an *iterator* object.

```py
from itertools import filterfalse


def check_word(word: str) -> bool:
    """Returns True iff the word starts with [ and ends with ]."""

    return word.startswith('[') and word.endswith(']')


filtered_words = filterfalse(check_word, words)
```

If you need to iterate over them more than once, you can convert the iterator into a sequence, e.g. a list:

```py
from itertools import filterfalse


def check_word(word: str) -> bool:
    """Returns True iff the word starts with [ and ends with ]."""

    return word.startswith('[') and word.endswith(']')


filtered_words = list(filterfalse(check_word, words))
```